# R: ifelse, return a subset based on a condition

Tags: r, if-statement, subset

I am still learning R and bumped into something that is beyond my comprehansion. I spent like 2 hours trying to figure it out on my own and failed :-( .

I have a data.frame (let's think of iris, for instance) that I want to subset using *ifelse*. If the 1st row is a "setosa", I want a data.frame back with first 50 rows, if not, the next 100 rows. See below.

```
data (iris)
a <- ifelse(iris$Species[1] == "setosa", iris[1:50,],iris[51:150,])
```

I would expect the above to return a subset of the original data.frame, but what I actually get is

```
[[1]]
 [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.6 5.0 4.4 4.9 5.4 4.8 4.8 4.3 5.8 5.7 5.4 5.1 5.7 5.1 5.4 5.1 4.6
[24] 5.1 4.8 5.0 5.0 5.2 5.2 4.7 4.8 5.4 5.2 5.5 4.9 5.0 5.5 4.9 4.4 5.1 5.0 4.5 4.4 5.0 5.1 4.8
[47] 5.1 4.6 5.3 5.0
```

I simply don't get it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read in `ifelse` docs that

> `ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as `test` which is filled
>   with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
>   element of `test` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

So if `test` is a vector, it returns a vector, if it is a single value it returns a single value etc. If you provide wrong arguments, it produces rubbish results. To give examples

```
> ifelse(1:10<5, 1, 0)
[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
> ifelse(1:10<5, 0, 1:10)
[1]  0  0  0  0  5  6  7  8  9 10
> ifelse(TRUE, 1, 0)
[1] 1
> ifelse(TRUE, 1:10, 0)
[1] 1
```

In your case you should rather use

```
if (condition) ... else ...
```

The `ifelse` and `if ... else ...` are different functions, `ifelse` is *not* a one-liner for the other function. What `ifelse` does is it goes through some object and replaces values in this object based on some `test` returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` for *each* value to be replaced.

Comment: Thank you :-). Quick and precise response. This function seemed to obvious for me to look it up in the documentation - my mistake.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that almost everyone discovers how it really works by such mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (iris$Species[1] == "setosa") a <- iris[1:50,] else a <- iris[51:150,]
```

or

```
a <- if (iris$Species[1] == "setosa") iris[1:50,] else iris[51:150,]
```

Comment: That implies that you know the indexes beforehand which usually is not a good idea

Comment: @vaettchen: like in the original question.
I dont know why user rpl want to do that.
also I suppose that rpl wants somthing like subset(iris, Species=="setosa") but the question was not about that.

Comment: True, but I guess this was for demonstrating the desired outcome rather than the intended solution. I'm not critisising your solution, just pointing out that hardcoding references / indexes usually is not good practice.

Comment: @vaettchen: jepp, i totally aggree

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the ifelse problem is given above.
Then depending on your actual application, you could also subset in this way:

```
subset(iris, Species==Species[1])
```